# LG UltraFine 5K monitor needs to be reconnected each time that it goes dark (Lenovo p15v and Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, lenovo

**Setup**

LG UltraFine 5K monitor connected to a Lenovo p15v Gen. 1 notebook running Ubuntu 20.04 through a Thunderbold 3 cable.

In principle, the monitor is working properly at 5K resolution. The issue is that it must be unplugged and reconnected each time that it goes dark. Otherwise it doesn't light up again.

**Scenario**

1. Turn the computer on. The display lights up. Enter the password to decrypt the file system and press enter. The screen goes dark and stays dark.
2. Unplug the thunderbolt cable and reconnect it. Wait a few seconds. The login screen is now visible.
3. Enter the login info and press enter. The screen goes dark and stays dark.
4. Unplug the thunderbolt cable and reconnect it. Wait a few seconds. The system is now usable.

When the screen goes dark after a period of inactivity or locking the screen, the same issue occurs: the cable must to be unplugged and reconnected for the monitor to light up again.

Using the notebook's integrated monitor and also boltctl I can see that the LG monitor is connected and actually used by the system. But the content is not visible because the back-light is off.

Using the docking station or connecting directly to the notebook does not seem to make a difference.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using xrand to configure the monitor. For example this set it to native resolution and turns off the internal monitor.

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 2560x2880 --pos 0x0 --output DP-2 --primary --mode 2560x2880 --pos 2560x0 --output eDP-1 --off
```

But this does not turn the back-light on.

This decreases/increases the brightness:

```
ddcutil setvcp 10 - 10
ddcutil setvcp 10 + 10
```

Unfortunately, increasing the brightness has no effect when the screen is dark. ddcutil can be used to turn *off* a monitor but I haven't found a way to turn it *on*.

- Is this a known issue? Is there a fix?
- Is there a command that can turn the back-light on?
- As a workaround, is there a command that would be equivalent to disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor so that, at least I don't have to fool around with the cable?